What is the mathematical definition of independence?
Given 2 events A and B, it's common to see the concept of independence being defined as several combinations of:

$P(A|B)=P(A)$
$P(B|A)=P(B)$
$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

What is correct to say? Condition 1 is necessary and sufficient to stablish what is called independence (because it would imply 2)? Condition 1 and 2 are the necessary ones? Condition 3 implies 1 and 2 and is the only one necessary? Some of them are a specific case of others?

The first two are exactly the same, just swap the labels.

Note:  this is "stochastic independence".  Not one of the other types of independence  like "linear independence", "algebraic independence", and so on.

Note that 3. applies even if one or both of the events has probability zero.

@Rick Tangential: For independent events A and B such that 0<P(B)<1,  P(A|B′)=P(A|B).

Independence of two events $A$ and $B$ in the sigma algebra $A, B \in \cal F$ of a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ is defined as
$$\Pr(A\cap B)= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$$
The other two $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B \mid A) = \Pr(B)$ cannot be used as definitions of independence because, for instance, $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A)$ requires $\Pr(B)\neq 0.$
Independent events cannot be understood intuitively as knowing about the event $B$ gives you no information about event $A$. The best example is explained here:
In the experiment of throwing a dart on the real line, $A=\text{lands on rational}$ and $B=\text{lands on an irrational}$. In this case, under the Lebesgue probability measure, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.$ Hence these events are independent. This is consistent with $\Pr(A)  \Pr(B)=0$ since the $\Pr(A)=0$. Yet, knowing that the dart has landed on an irrational number rules out the possibility of the dart having landed on a rational number.
The even more mind-blowing example is the extension to the event $B$ (irrational) being independent of itself: the probability of landing on an irrational under the Lebesgue measure is $1$, and therefore $\Pr(A \cap A)= \Pr(A)\Pr(A).$

Great , that's what I expected, I will vote it as an answer. Can you just add the important information that "If events A and B both have nonzero probabilities, then (1),(2),(3) are equivalent statements." as @ryang said in the comments? Also mention the equivalence between (1) and (2) as a consequence of the definition of P(A|B). And put the timestamp around 45:45 (or after in 46:20 if you want to point exactly to the experiment) in the link.

@Rick My interest was in dispelling the intuition of independent events based on information entropy. That being said, I believe the answer is complete wrt to the condition of $P(B) \neq 0$. The link is just intellectual honesty - listening to the entire lecture is highly recommended.

Yes, it's a good answer. Just a couple of extra explicit facts that made everything clearer to me (and are the answers to the questions I made in the post) and could be useful to others :)

First, I would just clarify what is the concept of independence.
So lets imagine you have two events $A$ and $B$, and we want to define independence, the easiest way to think about two events being independent is that knowing anything about the event $B$ will give you no information about the event $A$. Writing that in formal mathematics is saying $P(A|B)=P(A)$ that is the probability of $A$ knowing anything about $B$ is the same as just knowing the probability of $A$, $P(A)$.
And all the definitions you gave are the same, the first and the second being exactly the same one just by swapping $A$ with $B$. And the third comes from the conditional probability definition $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

I found out the proof of equivalence between the first 2, however it's not just a matter of swapping the labels, or else, P(A|B) would be the same as P(B|A). It's a consequence of the definition of P(A|B): https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Event_Independence_is_Symmetric
